# disable a spark button bar button by index

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

Can I disable a Spark Button Bar Button via an index value or do I have to do it through the buttons skin as shown [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/08/01/disabling-specific-buttons-in-a-spark-buttonbar-control-in-flex-4/) using the label.

and example of what I would like to do:

```
public function disableButton(index:uint):void
{
    var button:ButtonBarButton = this.getChildAt(index) as ButtonBarButton;

    button.enabled = false;


}
```

This does not work as the button object comes back null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you want is:

```
public function disableButton(index:int):void
{
    // Bounds check
    if (index < 0 || index >= this.dataGroup.numElements) return;

    var btn:ButtonBarButton = this.dataGroup.getElementAt(index) as ButtonBarButton;
    if (btn)
    {
        btn.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Here is a [complete working example](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/08/02/accessing-specific-buttons-in-a-spark-buttonbar-control-in-flex-4/).